# segue and transfer data from viewcontroller to viewcontroller to another viewcontroller

Tags: ios, swift3, segue

sorry for confusing title, but here is my problem. i do a segue from "superVC" (collectionviewcell) to "childVC" and its working well. then i want to segue again from that "childVC" to the "secondChildVC" (which is all the data is from superVC). is it possible? cause i always get a nil value when performing that segue.

its something like this : SuperVC -> ChildVC -> secondChildVC

here is the superVC segue:

```
var destination = [DestinationData]() 
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "DestinationDetailVC"{
        let detailVC = segue.destination as? DestinationDetailVC
        if let data = sender as? DestinationData{
            detailVC?.destinationDetail = data
        }
    }
}
```

here is 2nd vc segue

```
var destinationDetail : DestinationData?
@IBAction func goToMapOnPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    let detail = destinationDetail
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "DestinationMapVC", sender: detail )
    print(detail)
}
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "DestinationMapVC"{
        let detailVC = segue.destination as? DestinationMapVC
        if let data = sender as? DestinationData{
            detailVC?.destinationMapDetail = data
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: You can use the back button in the navigation controller to get to the previous viewcontroller.

Comment: err sorry for my bad explanation... i want to segue and also transfer data from ChildVC to secondChildVC , but data in ChildVC is from SuperVC. its something like SuperVC -> ChildVC -> secondChildVC , cause all the data is from superVC. @AbhishekBiswas

Comment: @RoccoBerry If I'm understanding your issue correctly you probably want to access some data in your SuperVC and later in the SecondChildVC. If so then I suggest you should use a __singleton__.

Comment: My pleasure @RoccoBerry. If you face any issue you may leave a msg here.

Comment: Are you able to get data in ChildVC from SuperVC?

Comment: @janmenjaya yes, i drag the segue from VC to VC and its works with my code. before this, i drag a segue from button to vc and not works.

Comment: @RoccoBerry, dragging from VC is fine, but my main concern is the data is array type and while navigating to nextVC you are checking other type (DestinationData), actually it should be array as your  "var destination" is an array of DestinationData. One more thing You need to pass the array or single  DestinationData from certain index of destination array?

Comment: i didnt pass the array data but only a single data. on SuperVC i created collectionview and data is passed fron didselectrowatindexpath which is this VC only send data from the selected cell. but i didnt insert the full code in here. @Janmenjaya

Comment: If you need to pass single data then first fetch the single data from the destination array, but you are passing the array and force cast it to Destination object, read my answer for help

Answer (score 0):

I think you are sending array of `DestinationData` to first segue, but inside the first segue you have put condition, so that if the data would be of `DestinationData` kind class, then the data will be sent to nextVC, But in actual you are sending array of `DestinationData` object so the if condition fails and hence the data are not passed to `childVC`

That's why you might be getting nil in the `secondChildVC` as there is no data in `destinationDetail` of `childVC`.

Hence you can modify the condition to check for array as the `destination` holds array type of data. or else remove the condition from the `prepareSegue` method.

**Code :**

```
//Write this code in to get that clicked object then pass that object in sender
let destTemp = sender[your selected index]

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "DestinationDetailVC"{
            let detailVC = segue.destination as? DestinationDetailVC
            if let data = sender as? DestinationData{
                detailVC?.destinationDetail = data
            }
        }
    }
```